# Convert single PNG image into single PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion, png

I need a method to convert single images (specifically PNG format) into PDF's that are automatically re-sized to fit that single image (and not remain the default 8.5x11" letter size). I could do this manually with Office or Open office, but it would take too long for a batch of files. I'm using Windows 7. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use [XNConvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/) (wasn't mentioned in the duplicates answers)

- batch processing
- automatic resize or predefined resize
- output as PDF (and various other formats)
- no installation necessary

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks, this method also worked perfectly to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Use windows print]

In windows you can use print for any number of images as pdf.

> 1. just select images and click print.
> 2. print as pdf.
> 3. save file.

Answer (score 0):

Download ImageMagick for Windows. [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

**Note:** Scroll down and read "**To verify ImageMagick is working properly, ...**"

Then you just have to type in the Command Prompt window:

```
cd \Users\<user name>\Pictures
convert file.jpg file.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'd upvote you but don't have enough rep. I ended up preferring IrfanView over your method.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method myself using free [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/main_download_engl.htm) software and installing the additional [PDF plugin (IMPDF)](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm). This software has been around since 1996, and is updated regularly and still very flexible/useful. It offers an easy-to-use GUI that even let me select multiple files for batch conversion.

It also has options for image compression quality and to keep the "page format" "like layout" that auto-resizes the PDF's, or even add security encryption if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Now a days online converters are used to convert multiple files realted to differnet industries. First you drop your image to specific area and then convert and save it to the computer.
Converter made life easy regarding to the files and documents.